# slow speed in aswtates update

Tags: apache-2.2, awstats, logging

I have installed AWStates to analyze my site apache log.

I have run the update command for the first time. size of log file is 250M.I run it about 10 mins ago and it is still working.

Is this slow speed in update command ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was slow because of DNS Lookup. I set to use GeoIP instead of DNSLookup in config file and it get solved.

Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The first run will most likely have to "thread through" all the existing logging to build up the stats. Subsequent runs should be new deltas against the existing stats at that point.